# Maxima of two functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Let three strictly increasing and positive functions of $x$: $f_1\left(x\right)$, $f_2\left(x\right)$ and $g\left(x\right)$. If $\forall x$, $f_1\left(x\right)>f_2\left(x\right)$, can I claim that:

$\arg \max_x f_1\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right)> \arg \max_x f_2\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right) $

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessarily correct. Consider functions $f_1,f_2,g$ that are piecewise linear on $[0,2]$ with values
$$
\begin{aligned}
&f_1(0) = 2, \, f_2(0) = g(0) = 1 \\ 
&f_1(1) = 10, \, f_2(1) = 2, \, g(1) = 3 \\ 
&f_1(2) = 11, \, f_2(2) = 10, g(2) = 5 
\end{aligned}
$$
Then
$$
\arg \max_x f_1\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right) = 1, \quad \arg \max_x f_2\left(x\right)-g\left(x\right) = 2 \, .
$$

Comment: Your $g$ is not strictly increasing, but this can be fixed by setting $g(1)=1.5$.